# 20.04 goes into suspend instead of power off, ASrock mobo

Tags: kernel, suspend, power-management, shutdown

Well, I checked other user questions, mostly related to laptops.
When I use the **power off** menu button on a standard 20.04 install, the computer goes into suspend mode, instead of powering off. No matter what I try, it will go into suspend (power LED blinking).

I tried `systemctl poweroff` from cmd line. I modified some config files. I disabled ACPI in BIOS etc.

The MoBo is a ASRock B450 with Ryzen 3 (Vega Graphics in CPU) and 16GB RAM.
Again, no matter what, it goes suspend with **Poweroff** selected.

This happened after an upgrade of whatever kernel it was. I don't keep a written log on updates, so I would not remember what kernel version caused it, plus I didn't realize immediately. The initial clean install (April 2020) did in fact rightly shut down the system. I suppose it isn't much of a operational problem, however it bugs the living out of me, when things don't work.

Any thoughts?
TNX

Answer (score 0):

You could try DConf graphical configuration editor.
The path to look for in this tool is '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power/power-button-action'...
There you can choose the action that the power button should excert...
It's also possible in the terminal but more cumbersome imo.

Comment: Hi @frankmcpeeters, thanks for your suggestion. I tried yours without avail. Still hung in suspend. If it bothers me too much, I'll just make a current backup of personal files and re-install, maybe even a different flavor.